# why this Google Chrome Extensions sample CatBlock don't work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i wana use some chrome.webRequest APIs like chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()，
google have provided some simple samples to demonstrate their usage.
just like the following extension plugin [CatBlock](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock.zip)

i place breakpoints in the background.js but it seems chrome never step into the function and no behavior show CatBlock works.

can anybody tell me the reason? thanks!

Comment: The example works just fine. How is it that you are trying to test it?

Comment: i have installed this plugin and then open the develop tools, set breakpoints in the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener() function , but it never step into it when i refresh a web page on chrome(cause a http request)

Comment: are you going to the [right site](http://icanhas.cheezburger.com/)